# Как написать функцию, которая ничего не возвращает, только измененяет переданный список?

Tags: python, функции

Задача следующая:

Напишите функцию `modify_list(l)`, которая принимает на вход список целых чисел, удаляет из него все нечётные значения, а чётные нацело делит на два. Функция не должна ничего возвращать, требуется только изменение переданного списка, например:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(modify_list(lst))  # None
print(lst)               # [1, 2, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)               # [1]

lst = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(lst)
print(lst)               # [5, 4]
```

Функция не должна осуществлять ввод/вывод информации."
Я решил попробовать решить вот так:

```
def modify_list(l):
    for i in l:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            return int(i / 2)
        else:
            del i


l = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(l)
print(l)
```

Если использовать `print` внутри самой функции (после первого условия `print(int(i / 2)`) ответ выдается корректный, но если использовать в конце, то выдается просто лист `l` без изменений.

В чем проблема моего решения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Объясните пожалуйста, в чем проблема моего решения

По условиям задачи:

> Функция не должна ничего возвращать, требуется только изменение переданного списка

А вы используете оператор `return`, который возвращает значение из функции и завершает ее выполнение на первом встретившемся четном числе.

---

попробуйте так:

```
def modify_list(l):
    for i in reversed(range(len(l))):
        if l[i] % 2 == 0:
            l[i] //= 2
        else:
            del l[i]
```

PS итерирование по списку выполняем в **обратном порядке**, чтобы избежать ошибки `IndexError: list index out of range`, которая практически запрограммирована при удалении элементов из списка во время итерирования по нему.

тесты:

```
In [20]: l = [1, 12, 5, 6, 100]

In [21]: modify_list(l)

In [22]: l
Out[22]: [6, 3, 50]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```py
def modify_list(l):
    l[:] = [x // 2 for x in filter(lambda x: x & 1, l)]

l = [10, 5, 8, 3]
print(l)
modify_list(l)
print(l) # [2, 1]
```